# Missing "Registration" page with BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress, user-registration

So, I'm a total newbie on BuddyPress and can't seem to understand how is it supposed to work... The question is simple: there is no registration page generated, and even though "Anyone can register" is ticked, when I manually added a login page, there is still no option for registration whatsoever... Any tips would be appreciated... 
The site where I'm trying to get this done is: http://eatstaylovelondon.com/

Comment: You probably have some custom or theme code that has disabled it. Where does the 'Coming soon' in upper left come from? If you deactivate BuddyPress, can you register?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://eatstaylovelondon.com/wp-login.php?action=register

You can create a register now link which will redirect to the above page.

Just adding "?action=register" at the end of the URL will do the work for you.

You can Create a Register page too.

Do Search how to display Register form.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by Aniket does solve the problem, however to save others the trouble, I'd like to say that it appears that woocommerce and BuddyPress cannot work together on a single website because apparently woocommerce disables the registration for WP